# Extract a single image by timestamp from GFS image collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to get one image, not a series of images, from GFS weather forecast data in Google Earth Engine.  This is what I am trying, or similar variations of it.

```
// date that we want to focus on
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GFS0P25')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('creation_time',ee.Date('2019-12-15').update(2019,12,15,0,0,0).millis()));
var temperatureAboveGround = dataset.select('temperature_2m_above_ground');

var visParams = {min: -40.0, max: 35.0, palette: ['blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'],};
Map.setCenter(71.72, 52.48, 0);
Map.addLayer(temperatureAboveGround, visParams, 'Temperature Above Ground');
```

This produces a row of what seems to be the same image at the bottom of the API.  How do I extract the map for one time stamp, for one variable, only?

Comment: Note that for a given `creation_time` there are a series of future forecasts extending out 384 hours at intervals of 1 and 3 hours. If you'd like to summarize all forecasts by a statistic, use Daniel's answer, otherwise, additionally filter by the `forecast_time` property to select a single particular time, which will be a single image (`filteredCollection.first()`).

Answer (score 0):

You have a whole range of options in turning your `temperatureAboveGround` into a single image. Here are some options, which should be pretty self explanatory:

```
temperatureAboveGround.first()
temperatureAboveGround.mean()
temperatureAboveGround.median()
temperatureAboveGround.min()
temperatureAboveGround.max()
temperatureAboveGround.reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev())
```

Look at the `ee.ImageCollection` and `ee.Reducer` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_reducing) for an exhaustive list and explanation.

Here's a working example:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/9d679076812bffd9030307696b825526